# GWT + Intel XDK

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, intel-xdk

I am not a big fan of JavaScript (perhaps because of I do not know it well), but now I have to use Intel XDK (HTML5 + JS).
So I think I will replace JS to Java with the help of Google Web Toolkit.
I am a beginner at GWT and Intel XDK too. I made an simple GWT project, compile it and insert the .html and .js files to my Intel XDK project.
The static elements (which are in the .html file) are shown, but the dynamic parts, which the JS has to generate, are not.
Does anybody try these two technologies together?? Can it work???

Thx.

Comment: I'm not familiar with what GWT generates. According to the overview it seems that you should be able to use this technique. Can you provide an example of the output of a simple app, it would help to figure out how to proceed. Might be easier if you posted something on the [XDK forum](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-xdk); attach a ZIP file containing the output of the tool to the post. Please make it a simple app that includes all the output (HTML, CSS, JS, images, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

The point of GWT is to write client side in Java.

I think that it is possible to use JavaScript produced in GWT compiler as source in Intel XDK (why not? it is a JavaScript after all), but I would recommend you to learn JavaScript instead and write directly.

For example with JQuery Mobile. You will fall in love with JavaScript very quickly.